# Django can't import generic view django.views.generic.date_based.object_detail

Tags: django

I am trying to use Django's generic views, but am getting an error when running `python manage.py runserver`. I've looked around for others who've experienced this problem and have not found anything. Here's the url pattern in my project's urls.py :

```
(r'^weblog/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\w{3})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$',
    'django.views.generic.date_based.object_detail', entry_info_dict),
```

And here's the error:

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x10c946668>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 93, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 101, in inner_run
    self.validate(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 310, in validate
    num_errors = get_validation_errors(s, app)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/validation.py", line 34, in get_validation_errors
    for (app_name, error) in get_app_errors().items():
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 196, in get_app_errors
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 75, in _populate
    self.load_app(app_name, True)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/loading.py", line 99, in load_app
    models = import_module('%s.models' % app_name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 40, in import_module
    __import__(name)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/models.py", line 63, in <module>
    patch_root_urlconf()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/debug_toolbar/models.py", line 51, in patch_root_urlconf
    reverse('djdt:render_panel')
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 480, in reverse
    app_list = resolver.app_dict[ns]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 310, in app_dict
    self._populate()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 285, in _populate
    lookups.appendlist(pattern.callback, (bits, p_pattern, pattern.default_args))
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 229, in callback
    self._callback = get_callable(self._callback_str)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 32, in wrapper
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/urlresolvers.py", line 103, in get_callable
    (lookup_view, mod_name))
django.core.exceptions.ViewDoesNotExist: Could not import django.views.generic.date_based.object_detail. Parent module django.views.generic.date_based does not exist.
```

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong here?

Comment: What version of django are you using?

Comment: Related: [What's current Django for “from django.views.generic import list_detail”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21361646/django-cant-import-generic-view-django-views-generic-date-based-object-detail)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to be using Django < 1.5 to use the function-based generic views. [They were depreciated in 1.3](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.3/#function-based-generic-views) and removed in 1.5 in place of [class based generic views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/class-based-views/)

> As a result of the introduction of class-based generic views, the function-based generic views provided by Django have been deprecated. The following modules and the views they contain have been deprecated:
>
> - django.views.generic.create_update
> - django.views.generic.date_based
> - django.views.generic.list_detail
> - django.views.generic.simple

Here is [the documentation for the new generic class based date views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/), specifically the [`DateDetailView`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#datedetailview)